# ¿Cómo eliminar una page en Ionic 2?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, ionic2

He eliminado una page en ionic 2 pero me sale un error. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se actualice el build/main.js

```
Error: Cannot find module "../address/address"
    at v (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:4864)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:82709:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:82792:75)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:100516:75)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:123745:70)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:66:18
    at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:69:10
```

Comment: Probablemente tendrás dependencias a esa pagina en el ngModule de tu app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que eliminar la referencia que se encuentra en app.module.ts :)